# Dynamic Bootstrap Carousel From Image Array

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

What i'm trying to do here is create a bootstrap carousel from an array containing image urls, i cannot see where i have messed up, currently it displays like: https://www.we-love-unicorns.club/301-baby-unicorn-top/ with one image on top of each other.

**My Code so far:**

```
<!-- Dynamic carousel -->

<div id="mainCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">

    <li data-target="#mainCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>

    <?php

        for ($c = 1; $c <= count($p['images']); $c++) {
            echo "<li data-target=\"#mainCarousel\" data-slide-to=\"".$c++."\"></li>";
        } 

    ?>

  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">

    <div class="item active">
    <?php

        for ($c = 0; $c <= count($p['images']); $c++) {
            echo "<img src=\"{$p['images'][$c]}\">";
        } 

    ?>
    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#mainCarousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>

  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#mainCarousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a> 
</div>

<!-- Dynamic carousel -->
```

At this part: **count($p['images']);** is where i do a count of the images in the array, then proceed from there to show the display, i feel i have missed something small but i cannot see where, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Based on Bootstrap version 4.0 documentation, it supposed to be `carousel-item` not `item` only. 
Besides, there should be only one image per `carousel-item`.

```
 <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
```